# Array Adapter Load Images from Res Folder (Android App)

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

Am an Android newbiew. Am trying to load a bunch of images in my res/Drawable folder into a Gridview via an array adapter. unfortunately my the app crashes each time i try to view the activity with the gridView. i would like to know how to set the imageResource of image i have in the res folder to display in the Gridview.

here is my Code:

Smile.class

```
    public class Smiley extends Activity {
    GridView gridView;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.smile);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    String planets[] = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.imageme);

     ArrayAdapter<String>adapter  = new  ArrayAdapter<String>  (this,R.layout.grid_view_row,R.id.imageGrid , planets);
     gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

   }    


  }
```

Smile.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/blurred"
  >

     <GridView
     android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:columnWidth="90dp"
     android:numColumns="auto_fit"
     android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
     android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:gravity="center"
     >
    </GridView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

grid_view_row.xml (Custom layout for the Gridview)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/a"
     />

  </FrameLayout>
```

My String Array(xml)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
   <string-array name="imageme">
   <item>@drawable/a</item>   
   <item>@drawable/b</item> 
   <item>@drawable/c</item> 
   <item>@drawable/d</item>  

   </string-array>

   </resources>
```

Logcat

```
    09-04 16:48:40.561: E/ArrayAdapter(25938): You must supply a resource ID for a           TextView
      09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938): java.lang.IllegalStateException:  ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
        09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):    at     android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
         09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   at      android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
      09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2207)
      09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):  at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1040)
    09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
     09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:645)
        09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:425)
        09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
      09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
     09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
       09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
     09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
     09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
       09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
       09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2203)
    09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
   09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
      09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
     09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
    09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
   09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
  09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
     09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
  09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
   09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
   09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
     09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
  09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
     09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
   09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:382)
     09-04 16:48:40.568: E/AndroidRuntime(25938):   ... 35 more
```

please help.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific answer to your issue is your constructor for your adapter is:

```
(this,R.layout.grid_view_row,R.id.imageGrid , planets);
```

`R.layout.grid_view_row` needs to be an xml file with only a `TextView`. It can't be wrapped in anything else like a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. So you would need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    //attributes
/>
```

However, If you want to load images into a `GridView` I would recommend using an "image adapter" that extends `BaseAdapter` and then get the images from there. Very similar to this example:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to your images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

}

where `getView` sets how the grid should look and `mThumbIds` is an `Array` of every picture that you want. From here in the `Activity` that you want to display the `GridView` in just add the code:

```
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you try to assign String-type data to `ImageView`. 
The easiest way to fix it would be:

1. Change resource array type to integer-array
2. Instead of using simple `ArrayAdapter` with string data, use custom adapter like:

   ```
   class ImgAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return planets.length;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer getItem(final int position) {
       return planets[position];
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(final int position) {
       return position;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
       final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_view_row, null);
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageGrid);
       imageView.setImageResource(getItem(position));
       return view;
   }
   }
   ```

That is simple it. Last thing is to set new adapter to `gridView`

Comment: Thanks!! i i just implemented you own answer it works too.tnanks again